# Find percentage of Wins/Draw/Losses of last X games played by a team

Tags: mysql

I have a table (test_matches) with a record of the results of several games, sorted by date.

[image]

GHFT = Goals Home Team Full Time.
GAFT = Goals Away Team Full Time.

```
CREATE TABLE `test_matches` (
 `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `match_date` date NOT NULL,
 `home_team` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
 `away_team` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  GHFT` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `GAFT` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  );
INSERT INTO test_matches (match_date, home_team, away_team, GHFT, GAFT ) 
VALUES ('2019-01-01', 'Real Madrid', 'Zaragoza', 2,0), 
('2019-01-03', 'Barcelona', 'Lugo', 1,1), 
('2019-01-04', 'Real Madrid', 'Lugo', 2,1), 
('2019-01-05', 'Barcelona', 'Compostela', 4,1),
('2019-01-06', 'Real Madrid', 'Barcelona', 0,2),
('2019-01-07', 'Barcelona', 'Zaragoza', 0,0);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0f16a/1

I tried this query:

```
SELECT home_team,
   ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN ghft > gaft = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) /COUNT(*) *100) AS W_Home_Team,
   ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN ghft = gaft = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) /COUNT(*) *100) AS D_Home_Team, 
   ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN ghft < gaft = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) /COUNT(*) *100) AS L_Home_Team 
FROM ( SELECT home_team, ghft, gaft FROM test_matches ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2) average 
GROUP BY home_team;
```

However, the result I get is not correct, since it is taking into account the last two records of the table, not the last two records of each team.

[image]

The correct result is:
Barcelona 50-50-0 and Real Madrid 50-0-50.

How can I calculate the percentages of the last 2 matches of each team?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this SELECT Statement

```
SELECT
  home_team
  , ROUND(SUM(IF(ghft > gaft,1,0)) / COUNT(*),2) * 100 W_Home_Team
  , ROUND(SUM(IF(ghft = gaft,1,0)) / COUNT(*),2) * 100 D_Home_Team
  , ROUND(SUM(IF(ghft < gaft,1,0)) / COUNT(*),2) * 100 L_Home_Team
FROM
  (SELECT 
    home_team
    ,match_date
    , ghft
    , gaft
    , IF(@team <> home_team,@rank := 0, @rank := @rank) dec1
    ,@rank := @rank+1 rnk
    ,@team := home_team
  FROM test_matches,(SELECT @rank := 0) r1,(SELECT @team := '') r2
  ORDER BY home_team,match_date) t1
 WHERE rnk < 3
 GROUP BY home_team
;
```

You get this result

```
home_team       W_Home_Team     D_Home_Team     L_Home_Team
Barcelona       50              50              0
Real Madrid     100             0               0
```

This rounds the division to two digit so that you will get 25,25 Procent. You will have to adept this to your needs.

The inner SELECT is only to get the correct number of games per club.

with `WHERE rnk < 3` you can change the number of games you need

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0f16a/18)

Comment: That worked! How could the query be modified to calculate the percentages grouped by home_team, taking into account not only the games played as home_team, but also as away_team. For example, Barcelona in its last two games (one as home_team and another as away_team) would have a 50 50 0 percentage.

Comment: This is a new Question and you didn#t maeked this question as answered or voted on it.  As you can see here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0f16a/30 you have to combine both select from away and home team and the use the sum to give you that percentage

Comment: Sorry, I voted, but until I don't reach 15 of reputation, it is not shown publicly. In the last query, I only see the results of Barcelona, not Real Madrid. Would something be missing to add?

Comment: Barcelona is the **only** club  that has a entry as home and away team, as you enter all Teams it will show all available clubs. .

Comment: And the last question, sorry for such annoyance. Right now, if I run the query for the last 10 matches, the results of the maximum number are shown, in this case 4, what is wrong. How could it be restricted that if the total number of matches is less than rnk, no results are shown for that specific team?

Comment: You have to change in **both** subquerys the line  **WHERE rnk < 3** for **10** matches this must be  **WHERE rnk < 11** for **5** matches  **WHERE rnk < 6** As i said in my answer the where Clause determines the number of Days that are selected.